# Перебор значений в python

Tags: python

Открываю файл следующим образом:

```
with open(proxy_file) as proxy:
    ips = [row.rstrip() for row in proxy]
```

Если я правильно помню, то все данные хранятся в следующем виде:

```
['1.2.3.4:80', '1.2.3.4:3128', '1.2.3.4:8080']
```

И так далее. Можно как-то сделать поочерёдный перебор этих адресов? А то у меня пока что получилось только случайный выбор из списка сделать.

```
index = random.randint(0,len(ips)-1)
proxies = {'http': ips[index]}
```

Comment: Можно. Воспользуйтесь циклом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте конструкцию for ... in

Например так:

```
for ip in ips:
    print('Ещё один айпишник - ' + str(ip))
```

Подробнее читайте здесь:
http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/for_loop/

Answer (score 2):

```
def get(proxy_file): yield from (row.rstrip() for row in open(proxy_file))
for row in get('file'): print(row)
```